# Can we ignore the size or put it in right way while creating SQL DDL Statements using .Net?

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

Background:

I am working on a task in which I need to Compare the table schema with metadata available in another db and based on differences I need to generate DDL statement to update the existing table.

Ex: 
Suppose metadata table is showing there is a change in size of some column.

Then .net code will return a DDL statement like,

```
"ALTER TABLE TABLE NAME ALTER COLUMNNAME DATATYPE(SIZE)"
```

But currently there is an issue with column with type datetime or int or any other datatype which will not need length, coz metadata table is having size for each an every data type.

So is there any way to ignore the size while creating a DDL statement, if sql datatype don't need it.

Need Some help as early as possible.

Comment: please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Answer (score 1):

No. If the data type does not require a size definition, SQL Server will raise an error when attempting to write a size definition:

```
ALTER TABLE SomeTableName
    ALTER ColumnName int(11)
```

will raise the error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'ColumnName'.

What you need to do is decide, based on the data type, whether to include the size definition in your DDL statement or not - this can easily be done using a switch (select case in VB.Net) statement - here's a sample code in c#:

```
var ddlColumn = $"ALTER COLUMN {columnName} {dataType}";
switch(dataType)
{
    case "char":
    case "varChar":
    case "nChar":
    case "nVarChar":
    // other data types where size is needed...
        ddlColumn += $" ({size})";
    break;
}

var ddlTable = $"ALTER TABLE {tableName} {ddlColumn};";
```

As SMor rightfully commented - the `max` size of text/binary columns might need special attention - it's int equivalent is -1. I don't know how you are getting your source meta data but if the max is translated to -1, in the resulting ddl you would still have to specify `max` and not -1.

Comment: careful with "max" string or binary types!

Comment: @SMor good point!